# Check if 2 Types are the Same

Tags: c#, types, comparison, windows-phone-8.1

I have an object of an unknown type.  I am trying to see if it is of a particular type.  I have tried:

```
obj.GetType() == typeof(Object)
```

and

```
obj.GetType().ToString().Equals(typeof(Object).ToString())
```

but neither of them work.

How can I check to see if it an object is of a particular type?  I need to find out if it is the exact type, not a superclass/subclass of that type.

In Windows Phone 8.1, I am trying to see what class the sender was sent from.

Comment: What do you mean `obj.GetType() == typeof(Object)` does not work? `(new Object()).GetType() == typeof(Object)` returns `true` as expected... Not very clear what you expect.

Comment: maybe i screwed smething else up then? ill look around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were very close.

If you want to see if an object instance is of Widget type, you'd check thusly:

```
 if (thisObj.GetType() == typeof(Widget))
```

The object must be *precisely* of the class you are checking for.   If you're looking for any descendant subtype, you could use the syntactically easier:

```
 if (thisObj is Widget)
```

(when you're trying to figure out who an event sender is, the second construct is probably more useful)

Comment: must mean sender in NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e) is not what I think it is then. thank you for your answer!